# drag and drop not working in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I have created the brand new project in android studio and selected the master detail flow activity.By default fragment_item_detail.xml is generated but I am unable to drag and drop any widgets.How can I enable this cool feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the layout editor here is a quick guide.
[Design a UI with Layout Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html)

If you have the xml file open you need to hit the Design tab at the bottom of the document window.